# Having a hard time rewriting codeigniter uri's

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am going through a few codeigniter tutorials online but I got stuck on rewriting uri's.

Here is my .htaccess code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase jrdash

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-D
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I also made this change to the config file.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

The .htaccess file is in the root project folder, and the project directory is jrdash within my xampp htdocs directory. I get a error when I try to load the page simply by typing in localhost/jrdash, I was getting the default Codeigniter screen before but then I made these changes and now I get an error.

Comment: What's with the `?` after `index.php` in each of your rewrite rules? Also, `RewriteBase` is rarely needed unless you're using an aliased directory. I recommend removing it

Comment: Im not sure, I copied the code from a tutorial I was watching.

Comment: Urgh, any tutorial you have to *watch* (I assume it's one of those awful videos from the phpcodeacademy YouTube channel) is not worth following.

Comment: I was watching PHP Codeigniter by BrutalStorm on Udemy. Was not sure how to approach learning Codeigniter so I figured that would be a good start. Any recommendations?

Comment: @Phil `.htaccess` is not my strong suit but that question mark has made some of my projects work correctly in certain hosting environments where they will fail without it

Comment: did you find the solution? Please share i also facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove everything between the first and last-three lines and remove that question mark.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: That changed the error message, I am getting a Internal Server Error

Comment: @user2684521 What does your Apache error log say? You also had the wrong case for the `-d` flag. I've fixed that up

Comment: [Wed Jul 09 17:58:54 2014] [error] [client ::1] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: @user2684521 That's odd. Is this the only `.htaccess` file and is it in your `jrdash` directory?

Comment: it is but there is also a .htaccess file in the applications directory and that one just has Deny from all

Comment: You know what is weird, I added the question mark back in the .htaccess code. I refreshed and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read your whole question because I'm pretty sure you've made the very classical mistake: your forgot to add the **`QSA`** directive!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase jrdash

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-F
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-D
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```